# Haste II Beacon not working

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I have built a Beacon - full pyramid using Iron Blocks.

[image: Full Beacon]

It is completely solid. I then chose the buffs - Haste II, as well as Regen for having the full pyramid, then activated it using an Iron Ingot.

[image: Haste II - Iron Ingot]
[image: Haste II status effect]

However, even though I have the Haste II status effect applied, (the icon appears in my HUD, and the counter refreshes every 3 seconds), it has *not* applied the Regen (no icons appeared on my HUD) and it does not seem to actually apply to my digging speed at all - I have tried with two different Picks, one with Efficiency V, and one without. It takes just as long to mine if I did *not* have the Haste II enchantment applied at all.

Comment: Did you put the iron ingot in, select the effect *on the right* and then click on the check mark?

Comment: @Fabian Tbh, I'm really not sure. What I do know is that I placed in the Iron Ingot, selected the effect on the *left*, then hit the check mark. This is when I noticed the effect wasn't applied, even though the icon was on the HUD. I know I did come back *later* and attempt to select the regen effect, since it wasn't applied.

Comment: The buttons on the right represent a *choice*: you can have Haste II *or* Regen, **but not both**. Just like the buttons on the left represent exclusive choices. So everything seems to be operating as expected, except you say “it does not seem to effect my digging speed at all”. Why do you say that? What are you seeing or not seeing? Have you run formal tests? Try turning the beacon off, timing how long it takes to dig down to bedrock, then turn it on, and again time how long it takes to dig to bedrock, and compare the times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, as Fabian suggested in the comments, I missed a step.

1. Build the beacon, and the appropriate pyramid size.
2. Choose your enchantment from the *left* side to add it to the list of available enchantments
3. Select it from the *right* side to "turn it on".
4. Power it with an item.

I missed step 3.

I still don't understand why the effect appeared on my HUD, when it had not properly been selected in the beacon, it may be a bug, but I don't know.

Comment: The effects on the left are level 1. If you only want haste 1 (for whatever reason), then you can choose it there.

Comment: With haste 1 you can't insta-mine stone and the increase in mining speed is small, so that's probably why you didn't see a difference.

Answer (score 1):

> It is completely solid. I then chose the buffs - Haste II, as well as Regen for having the full pyramid, then activated it using an Iron Ingot.

Nope, you didn't. You chose Haste I and Regen. Regen and Haste II are mutually exclusive within the same single beacon - to have Haste II you have to pick Haste I on the left side, and Haste II on the right. If you click Regen on the right, you only have Haste I and Regen.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem but I figured it out I had made the 9x9 pyramid all the way and tried to apply haste 2 but only would give me haste 1, when I inspected the pyramid properly turned out I missed an iron block when Building the pyramid which stopped the beacon from accessing the secondary power.
Hoping this helps ;D

Comment: Hi Salman, that was never the problem, as you could have known from the question and the two-year old answer.